# Como filtrar tipo dato datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola amigos tengo esta consulta:

```
--SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
declare @variable date,@variable2 date
set @variable='2016-09-05'
set @variable='2016-09-06'
select convert(date,FechaCargo,103) as FechaCargo,* from FACTURACION.dbo.RelacionFacturasObservadas
where
 @variable>=convert(date,FechaCargo,103) and @variable2<=convert(date,FechaCargo,103) and 
Aseguradora+' '+Producto='PACÍFICO SOAT SEGURO'
--order by FechaCargo asc
```

Intento filtrar por un campo datetime y no me sale nada .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, a la variable variable2 no le has asignado nada, ya que los dos valores se lo has puesto a variable

Comment: Por qué estás convirtiendo la columna FechaCargo? Cuál es su tipo de dato? Por lo general, es una mala práctica que evita que se usen índices y estadísticas disponibles para la columna. De igual forma, es mejor hacer la comparación de forma independiente con Aseguradora y Producto.